# MVC3 ViewModels Saving Edited Data and Concurrency Checks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, concurrency, viewmodel

Following this tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), I learned how to save data and do concurrency checks on data before the data is submitted.

Now, I have a view that uses a ViewModel instead of the actual data model.

(1) How do I save the data back to the database when the form posts?
I can no longer call db.SaveChanges(); because the data is in the type of  ViewModel instead of Model.

(2) How do I perform a concurrency check on the data?

I'm just looking for a simple example to follow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same way, but you have to copy the data from the ViewModel to the Data Model when it's submitted, or you need to construct a new Entity from the view model and attach it to the DbSet.

You can use a tool such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to ease this process.

Comment: Do I need to do anything special with the Timestamp field in order for the concurrency check to work?

Comment: @user1304444 - you do whatever you were doing before, except that you don't rely on MVC to build your entity.  You have to do it yourself from the data returned by your view model.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for answering the simple question.  I think that will get me going.